# How to call a method after so many seconds?

Tags: c#

In my project I would like to be able to call a method after 3 minutes have passed. There is no "main loop" to speak of so I cannot use a stopwatch and constantly check if 3 minutes have passed. The only other solution I can think of is a Timer object with an interval of 3 minutes but that seems rather messy because it will only be called once after the 3 minute delay.

Thanks for reading.

Edit: Forgot to mention. This is for a server application so I cannot pause the execution of the thread because other stuff will have to be handled in the meantime. Also, this timer mechanism will not be alone. There may be hundreds of even thousands of concurrent timers at a time.

Comment: How accurate does the execution need to be? If it happens a few seconds after it was supposed to, what is the consequence?

Comment: Well for my application the client has 3 minutes to do something. The client keeps track of the time through javascript and the server keeps track of the time through (timers I suppose). To avoid cheating, once the three minutes have passed on the server, the server will send a message to the clients. It has to be pretty exact or people might get upset. Synching may become a problem and I'm not sure how I will handle that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really believe your idea with the `Timer` object is the right way to go.  It sounds like you're familiar with how to use it - but here's an example:

```
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 60 * 3);
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: Timers should not be used if he is going to be creating hundreds or thousands of these

Comment: you could disable the timer in the event handler using Timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)

Comment: Thousands may have been a bit much. It all just depends on how many clients the server has. If each room has 15 clients and there is one timer per room, if I ever reach a point where timers are no longer a good solution I can change it then, I suppose. Will probably never even reach that point though so I suppose I'll go with the timer approach.

Comment: you could probably use a single timer to handle all thousands. put all of the clients in a list and change your timer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

if you have hundreds or thousand of those timers, some scheduling will do the job.

You really should investigate [quartznet](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

lots of concurrent timers perform not very well as i experienced, quartznet will do.

and if you really want to have those scheduling tasks in your application, perhaps this article gives you some ideas [Task Scheduler Class Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2407/A-New-Task-Scheduler-Class-Library-for-NET)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Timer.

While there will be a slight overhead if you create a 1000 timers, it won't be too much. Timers will do their job and fire an event when 3 minutes have passed. Also, if you want your code to repeat every 3 minutes, Timers are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Timer is not a good solution for hundreds/thousands, as Timers are a limited resource.

Are all the methods to be called from the same application?

If so, I would create a small stub class that had a datetime, and an Action, and add delegates to the method to be called, along with the target time. Then in a background thread loop through the list and call the delegates when appropriate (and remove them obviously)

An alternate solution would be to do something like QueueUserWorkItem for each method to be called, and first thing in the thread sleep for the appropriate amount of time until the method should be called.

For all solutions (mine and others), be aware of any marshaling you have to do if you are interacting with the GUI, or any locking that may need to be done to avoid threading concurrency issues

Comment: thread sleep is not a very good solution. ticking every second on the queue and looking for jobs to be done is far better. if the job is fired, it should be placed on the queue again, but one must take care of race conditions AND jobs that may take longer than that period that the job shall be fired.

Comment: I'm not sure about marshaling or any of that. After 3 minutes the server just has to send a simple message to the respective room.

Answer (score -3):

After trying out several options, the method was not self-triggering. Hence, I used Javascript to solve the same problem as shown below.

```
<script>
function Timer() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Timer", "Exam")",//Method to call. Timer Method in Exam Controller
        type: 'GET', // <-- make a async request by GET
    dataType: 'html', // <-- to expect an html response
    cache: false,
    async: true
    });
}
setInterval(function () { Timer(); }, 5000);//Triggers method Timer() after 5 seconds
</script>
```

Comment: This is not a Javascript question.