# I need to send mail to 5 contacts by time delay of 30 secs one after another

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am using a grid view and sending mails to multiple users..I have coded to sent it at the same time..But I need the mails to be sent with a time delay..for example if the first person in the list receives the mail at 10:01 am then the second person should receive the mail at 10.02 am..Is there any possibility for that.
Kindly refer me ideas..
Thank you

Comment: Do you want schedule mail with one minute delay?

Comment: yes..nearly like that..so that the persons in the list should not receive the mail at the same time.

Comment: Refer this you can schedule a task in c# https://stackoverflow.com/a/24371520/795683

Comment: Use https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ for scheduling your emails

Comment: Actually I am using a web application..I need it to be solved in the code behind file itself..

Comment: You are not clear if you want the users to receive with time delay or if you want to send with time delay. Two very different problems.

Comment: @Sentinel users to receive with time delay

Comment: You can't control receive time as message delivery depends on network and some time mails take little longer than normal time.

Comment: @shanifaS In this case your closest approximation would be to implement hooks into a mail read-receipt confirmation from the mail server or a 3rd party mail service, using a default timeout for when the mail read receipt is blocked by recipient privacy. If you have some control over the network, eg: if this is for an in-house mail system, you may talk to the sysadmin about making internal read-receipt confirmation mandatory, etc. Just delaying send time by 30 seconds is not really going to have much effect on receipt times.

Comment: @Sentinel not exactly 30 secs..it can be 1 minute r more but not more than 5 min

Answer (score 1):

Use Quartz Scheduler for .NET for scheduling the emails. Check a sample implementation here. Let me know if you have any questions 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/job-scheduling-in-Asp-Net-mvc-with-quartz-net/

Comment: This is the best answer. Don't use Thread.Sleep in production like others suggested!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your code is (pseudo code)

```
for(int i=0; i< myList.Count; i++){
myList.sendSmtp();
}
```

(or something close), so how about

```
for(int i=0; i< myList.Count; i++){
myList.sendSmtp();
Task.Delay(30000); // or Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
```

am I getting close?

Comment: yes..so using 'Task.Delay' or ' Thread.Sleep' will causes the mail received time different to all users in the list right??..

Comment: But this does mean that the response takes minutes to complete - it would be better to move this to a fire-and-forget thread

Comment: short answer - yep, it sure will. long answer - it takes two to tango, and it takes two to read an email (one for sending one for recieving). the time the mail is recieved is not the same as the time it is sent.

Comment: @shanifaS No. You have no guarantees on when or even if the mail will be received.

Answer (score 0):

you can run batch file with wait command

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000); // say 1 minute
```

use above line if the time period is less but if you want time period like 24 hours you should use scheduled task.

Comment: Thank you the mails are received at different time..but it is showing timeout error